# Clear cells in a column of values if it has strings

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to write / find a macro that when ran removes the value in a cell if the cells in the column is not a number. IE remove all the cells in column B if a string is found. I have this script to delete empty rows. 
Was just trying to re write it so that it can delete the rows based on these condiitions

```
Sub RemoveRows()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim ISEmpty As Long

lastrow = Application.CountA(Range("A:XFD"))

Range("A1").Select


Do While ActiveCell.Row < lastrow

ISEmpty = Application.CountA(ActiveCell.EntireRow)


If ISEmpty = 0 Then
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code iterates backward from the last cell in column B and checks if the value in the cell is numeric using the `IsNumeric()` function.

If the value is not numeric then it deletes the entire row.

*Note:* looping backwards (ie. from the last row to first) is necessary when using a loop because the index gets shifted everytime a row gets deleted. Therefore, to avoid skipping some rows backward iteration is required.

```
Sub KeepOnlyNumbers()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim i As Long
    ' iterating backwards (from last row to first to keep the logic flow)
    For i = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        ' check whether the value is numeric
        If Not IsNumeric(Range("B" & i)) Then
            ' if not numeric then clear the cells content
            Range("B" & i).ClearContents
        End If
    Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I dont want to delete the row, just clear out the text

Comment: yes that works but all my dates are deleted even after i explicitly format the dates as numbers (since they were 01-Jan-2010) before

Comment: @SleepParalysis Dates are stores as numbers in Excel. They are displayed as Dates (mm/dd/yyyy for example) but they are stores as numbers. Gotta be careful using `isNumeric()` on dates

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IsNumeric` to evaluate if an object can be evaluated as a number. So you can add:

```
If Not IsNumeric(ActiveCell) Then
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
```

to your Do While loop and it should do what you want.  I haven't tested this; let me know if you get an error.

Comment: it won't do what the op wants because you have to iterate backwards when deleting rows

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to iterate backwards even when deleting rows, you can do union and call delete/clear on the unioned range.

```
Sub UnionOnCondition()

    Dim usedColumnB
    Set usedColumnB = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, _
                                ActiveSheet.Columns("b"))

    If usedColumnB Is Nothing Then _
        Exit Sub

    Dim result: Set result = Nothing
    Dim cellObject

    For Each cellObject In usedColumnB

        ' skip blanks, formulas, dates, numbers
        If cellObject = "" Or _
            cellObject.HasFormula Or _
            IsDate(cellObject) Or _
            IsNumeric(cellObject) Then GoTo continue

        If result Is Nothing Then
            Set result = cellObject.EntireRow
        Else
            Set result = Union(result, cellObject.EntireRow)
        End If

continue:
    Next

    If Not result Is Nothing Then _
        result.Select ' result.Clear or result.Delete

End Sub
```